# Name for shared resource mechanism in Racket

Tags: racket

I could just ask this on the mailing list, but this way the answer will be archived for posterity.

I seem to recall that there's a set of primitives in Racket that allow the sharing of a resource at the process level. For instance, suppose there's a (non-Racket) shared library whose initialization produces a unique token used to communicate with it (bad idea, I know). What's the best way to share this with all threads that need to access it?

Many thanks!

EDIT: clearly I did an extraordinarily poor job of explaining myself. The fundamental issue here is that I have a DrRacket tool that runs at init time, and a user thread that runs in a user's eventspace, and the challenge is to communicate a value from the one to the other. One obvious but grotesque way would be to alter the behavior of the "run" button for all DrRacket programs. Another way would be to ...

Okay, perhaps the right question is whether there's an easy way for all instantiations of a module to share a mutable box.

Comment: Would this be a custom port? When I've run into this problem (multiple times) I use your "extreme fallback position" and have some kind of master manage the process, either a thread itself or some kind of object which creates threads to handle the communication, depending on whether I need synchronous or asynchronous behavior (I've had to deal with both on the same system writing an interface to multiple distinct pieces of dissimilar hardware). If there's a nicer solution I'd be overjoyed.

Comment: No... there's a thing! What's it called! Not plumbers, not custodians, not security guards... grr.

Comment: Although... it sounds like your problem may be different from mine. How do you share an object between, e.g., the DrRacket eventspace and the user's eventspace? This is my problem.

Comment: I must be misunderstanding you, because isn't that the default behavior? That is, if you have some variable `shared-token`, any threads you spawn in its scope can read or `set!` it. What am I missing?

Comment: Or are you using separate `place`s? In which case maybe you're looking for `shared-bytes`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be thinking of [`scheme_register_process_global`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/inside/Miscellaneous_Utilities.html#%28cpp._scheme_register_process_global%29). It's used, for example, to avoid initializing the OpenSSL library multiple times; see `openssl/mzssl.rkt` near the end of the file.

Comment: Yes! this is what I was thinking of. Now that I look at it, though, I feel like there must be a nicer way than dipping into "void *" world. Hmm.

Comment: @JohnClements, if you just want a DrRacket tool to provide extra services to user land, look at the way the RackUnit tool does it at `pkgs/rackunit-plugin-lib/rackunit/tool.rkt`. OTOH, that will only make them available in the one namespace, at phase 0, but that might be enough in practice.